# Need some help completing a bumptop-ish selection tool

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bumptop

I'm in the midst of creating a Bumptop styled selection tool. Right now I got as far as creating the tool itself (which actually works pretty good) and spreading some random square items on the stage. This is the class that creates the selection tool :

```
package com.reyco1.medusa.selectiontool
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    
    public class SelectionBase extends Sprite
    {
        private var points:Array = [];
        
        public function SelectionBase()
        {
            super();
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initialize);
        }
        
        private function initialize(e:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initialize);
            
            points.push(new Point(mouseX, mouseY));          stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouseMove);
        }
        
        private function handleMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void
        {           
            graphics.clear();
            
            graphics.beginFill(0x33CCFF, .5);
            graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
            graphics.endFill();
            
            graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
            graphics.lineStyle(1.5, 0x33CCFF, .5);
            graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
            
            points.push(new Point(mouseX, mouseY));
            
            graphics.beginFill(0x33CCFF, .1);
            graphics.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
            
            for (var i:uint = 1; i < points.length; i++)
            {
                graphics.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
            }
            
            graphics.lineTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
            graphics.endFill();
            
            dispatchEvent(new Event("UPDATE"));
        }
        
        public function clear():void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouseMove);
            graphics.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the document class that implements it :

```
package
{
    import com.reyco1.medusa.selectiontool.SelectionBase;
    
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageQuality;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

    [SWF(width = '1024', height = '768', backgroundColor = '0x000000')]
    public class SelectionToolPrototype extends Sprite
    {
        private var selectionTool:SelectionBase;
        
        public function SelectionToolPrototype()
        {                         
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.quality = StageQuality.MEDIUM;
                    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleDown);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,     handleUp);  
            
            placeShapesRandomly();
        }
        
        private function placeShapesRandomly():void
        {
            for(var a:Number = 0; a<25; a++)
            {
                var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
                s.graphics.beginFill(Math.random() * 0xCCCCCC);
                s.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
                s.graphics.endFill();
                s.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 900 - 40) + 40;
                s.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 700 - 40) + 40;
                s.rotation =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 360 - 40) + 40;
                s.buttonMode = true;
                addChild(s);
            }
        }
        
        private function handleUp(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            selectionTool.removeEventListener("UPDATE", handleToolUpdate);
            removeChild(selectionTool);
            selectionTool = null;
        }
        
        private function handleDown(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            selectionTool = new SelectionBase();
            selectionTool.addEventListener("UPDATE", handleToolUpdate);
            selectionTool.x = mouseX;
            selectionTool.y = mouseY;
            addChild(selectionTool);
        }
        
        private function handleToolUpdate(e:Event):void
        {
            // logic to determin if items are within selection goes here        
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried using collision detection by means of BitmapData and even using collision libraries like CDK but I cant get anything to work. Anybody have an idea what I should use in the `handleToolUpdate(e:MouseEvent);` ? Thanks!

#### Update:

I'll break it down. Basically I am trying to create a prototype of the BumpTop Lasso or Selection tool.

I need help in finding out which objects either collide or have a point within the bounds  of the drawn lasso.

I have upload what I have so far to my server here : http://labs.reyco1.com/bumptop/SelectionToolPrototype.html. You can see the source by right clicking and selecting "View Source".

Like I said in my earlier post, I tried using Bitmapdata collision testing and even tried using the Collision Detection Kit to no avail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: as for very raw way: you can make **for each** cycle and measure each component to fit your selection rectangle.

Comment: that's kinda vague. lol. Could you elaborate a bit? And thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't actually specify what it is that you need to do. Could you try asking about the core of your problem, separately from the overall application you're making? (i.e. "How can I do collision tests in a BitmapData under the following conditions?" or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the display object you are attaching your random sprites to, and using for each, check their value of hitTestObject against your selectionTool instance.

Here are the Adobe docs for hitTestObject():

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29